# How to style class in functions.php

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I added I some classes to my functions.php like so:

```
add_action('admin_menu',
    'wpso_custom_links_admin_menu');

function wpso_custom_links_admin_menu() {
        global $submenu;
        $submenu['index.php'][] = array('Link One', 'read',
            'https://www.example.com/', '', 'jobs-dashboard');
        $submenu['index.php'][] = array('Link Two', 'read',
            'https://asdf.com/', '', 'events-dashboard
            ');
        }
```

Then I added css:

```
. jobs-dashboard {background-color: green;}
```

Didn't work. Why not? [image]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEdMC.jpg[image][image]

Comment: `.jobs-dashboard` try without space between `.` and class name

Comment: Seems like TYPO mistake. `. jobs-dashboard` needs to be `.jobs-dashboard`. No spaces between `.` and class name while applying css

Comment: Thanks but that's just Stack Overflow typesetting layout...space doesn't appear in edit/ pre-publish page...

Comment: Show us what the markup looks like in the DOM - can you screenshot the DevTools view?

Comment: How do I add a screenshot here?

Comment: by using this:- https://prnt.sc/o2v6s9  . but better to add rendered makr-up HTML and css code

Comment: where you added this css?

Comment: @shivendra in my additional css box..

Comment: Where you added this style that css file should be register with admin_enqueue_scripts. like function admin_style() {
  wp_enqueue_style('admin-styles', get_template_directory_uri().'/admin.css');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_style');

Comment: @shivendra yes, I checked in `view-source` and it has been registered. It's there.

Comment: Then it's should be work. I tried it's working. Just clear the catch and see. after clear the catch if it's not working add important like - .jobs-dashboard {background-color: green !important;}

Comment: @shivendra see site https://adsler.co.uk also see screenshot above. Still not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195059/discussion-between-shivendra-singh-and-stackinnerflow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using your themes additional CSS option, which is typically for front end CSS changes.

To add CSS to the admin area you can use the `admin_head` hook in your functions.php.

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_css');
function my_custom_css() {
  echo '<style>
    .jobs-dashboard {background-color: green;}
  </style>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked. But why doesn't it let me add `color:white;`? Also, can I add multiple classes to it like so? `add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_css');
function my_custom_css() {
  echo '<style>
    .jobs-dashboard.events-dashboard1 {background-color: green; color:white;}? 
  </style>';
}`?

Comment: @Stackinnerflow Yes you can add as many styles and selectors as you want. Just make sure all of your css is inside that `<style></style>` tag. In regards to the `color:white` not working. Firstly inspect the element you are trying to change the color of and make sure it is not being overridden by another style or you are targeting the wrong element. If you are struggling and it is definitely the right element, you can try `color:white!important;`

Comment: Thanks. You live up to your name :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't work because you put a space in you class:

```
. jobs-dashboard {background-color: green;}
```